# trying to debug this source code, stuck on some simple syntax errors

Tags: pine-script

I keep getting the error `no viable alternative character at line 147` where `// functions` start. Not quite sure what I'm missing. Any help is appreciated. Im trying to debug a source code I got that resembles MarketCipher, this is too focus on divergence.

```
//@version=4
study(title = "VuManChu B Divergences", shorttitle = "VMC Cipher_B_Divergences")

// PARAMETERS {

// WaveTrend
wtShow = input(true, title = "Show WaveTrend", type = input.bool)
wtBuyShow = input(true, title = "Show Buy dots", type = input.bool)
wtGoldShow = input(true, title = "Show Gold dots", type = input.bool)
wtSellShow = input(true, title = "Show Sell dots", type = input.bool)
wtDivShow = input(true, title = "Show Div. dots", type = input.bool)
vwapShow = input(true, title = "Show Fast WT", type = input.bool)
wtChannelLen = input(9, title = "WT Channel Length", type = input.integer)
wtAverageLen = input(12, title = "WT Average Length", type = input.integer)
wtMASource = input(hlc3, title = "WT MA Source", type = input.source)
wtMALen = input(3, title = "WT MA Length", type = input.integer)

// WaveTrend Overbought & Oversold lines
obLevel = input(53, title = "WT Overbought Level 1", type = input.integer)
obLevel2 = input(60, title = "WT Overbought Level 2", type = input.integer)
obLevel3 = input(100, title = "WT Overbought Level 3", type = input.integer)
osLevel = input(-53, title = "WT Oversold Level 1", type = input.integer)
osLevel2 = input(-60, title = "WT Oversold Level 2", type = input.integer)
osLevel3 = input(-75, title = "WT Oversold Level 3", type = input.integer)

// Divergence WT
wtShowDiv = input(true, title = "Show WT Regular Divergences", type = input.bool)
wtShowHiddenDiv = input(false, title = "Show WT Hidden Divergences", type = input.bool)
showHiddenDiv_nl = input(true, title = "Not apply OB/OS Limits on Hidden Divergences", type = 
input.bool)
wtDivOBLevel = input(45, title = "WT Bearish Divergence min", type = input.integer)
wtDivOSLevel = input(-65, title = "WT Bullish Divergence min", type = input.integer)

// Divergence extra range
wtDivOBLevel_addshow = input(true, title = "Show 2nd WT Regular Divergences", type = 
input.bool)
wtDivOBLevel_add = input(15, title = "WT 2nd Bearish Divergence", type = input.integer)
wtDivOSLevel_add = input(-40, title = "WT 2nd Bullish Divergence 15 min", type = 
input.integer)

// RSI+MFI
rsiMFIShow = input(true, title = "Show MFI", type = input.bool)
rsiMFIperiod = input(60,title = "MFI Period", type = input.integer)
rsiMFIMultiplier = input(150, title = "MFI Area multiplier", type = input.float)
rsiMFIPosY = input(2.5, title = "MFI Area Y Pos", type = input.float)

// RSI
rsiShow = input(false, title = "Show RSI", type = input.bool)
rsiSRC = input(close, title = "RSI Source", type = input.source)
rsiLen = input(14, title = "RSI Length", type = input.integer)
rsiOversold = input(30, title = "RSI Oversold", minval = 50, maxval = 100, type = 
input.integer)
rsiOverbought = input(60, title = "RSI Overbought", minval = 0, maxval = 50, type = 
input.integer)

// Divergence RSI
rsiShowDiv = input(false, title = "Show RSI Regular Divergences", type = input.bool)
rsiShowHiddenDiv = input(false, title = "Show RSI Hidden Divergences", type = input.bool)
rsiDivOBLevel = input(60, title = "RSI Bearish Divergence min", type = input.integer)
rsiDivOSLevel = input(30, title = "RSI Bullish Divergence min", type = input.integer)

// RSI Stochastic
stochShow = input(true, title = "Show Stochastic RSI", type = input.bool)
stochUseLog = input(true, title= "Use Log?", type = input.bool)
stochAvg = input(false, title= "Use Average of both K & D", type = input.bool)
stochSRC = input(close, title = "Stochastic RSI Source", type = input.source)
stochLen = input(14, title = "Stochastic RSI Length", type = input.integer)
stochRsiLen = input(14, title = "RSI Length", type = input.integer)
stochKSmooth = input(3, title = "Stochastic RSI K Smooth", type = input.integer)
stochDSmooth = input(3, title = "Stochastic RSI D Smooth", type = input.integer)

// Divergence stoch
stochShowDiv = input(false, title = "Show Stoch Regular Divergences", type = input.bool)
stochShowHiddenDiv = input(false, title = "Show Stoch Hidden Divergences", type = input.bool)

// Schaff Trend Cycle
tcLine = input(false, title = "Show Schaff TC line", type=input.bool)
tcSRC = input(close, title = "Schaff TC Source", type = input.source)
tclength = input(10, title= "Schaff TC", type=input.integer)
tcfastLength = input(23, title= "Schaff TC Fast Lenght", type=input.integer)
tcslowLength = input(50, title= "Schaff TC Slow Length", type=input.integer)
tcfactor = input(0.5, title= "Schaff TC Factor", type=input.float)

// Sommi Flag
sommiFlagShow = input(false, title = "Show Sommi flag", type = input.bool)
sommiShowVwap = input(false, title = "Show Sommi F. Wave", type = input.bool)
sommiVwapTF = input(720, title = "Sommi F. Wave timeframe", type = input.string)
sommiVwapBearLevel = input(0, title = "F. Wave Bear Level (less than)", type = input.integer)
sommiVwapBullLevel = input(0, title = "F. Wave Bull Level (more than)", type = input.integer)
soomiFlagWTBearLevel = input(0, title = "WT Bear Level (more than)", type = input.integer)
soomiFlagWTBullLevel = input(0, title = "WT Bull Level (less than)", type = input.integer)
soomiRSIMFIBearLevel = input(0, title = "Money flow Bear Level (less than)", type = 
input.integer)
soomiRSIMFIBullLevel = input(0, title = "Money flow Bull Level (more than)", type = 
input.integer)

// Sommi Diamond
sommiDiamondShow = input(false, title = "Show Sommi diamond", type = input.bool)
sommiHTCRes = input(60, title = "HTF Candle Res. 1", type = input.string)
sommiHTCRes2 = input(240, title = "HTF Candle Res. 2", type = input.string)
soomiDiamondWTBearLevel = input(0, title = "WT Bear Level (More than)", type = input.integer)
soomiDiamondWTBullLevel = input(0, title = "WT Bull Level (Less than)", type = input.integer)

// macd Colors
macdWTColorsShow = input(false, title = "Show MACD Colors", type = input.bool)
macdWTColorsTF = input(240, title = "MACD Colors MACD TF", type = input.string)

darkMode = input(false, title = "Dark mode", type = input.bool)

// Colors
colorRed = #ff0000
colorPurple = #e600e6
colorGreen = #3fff00
colorOrange = #e2a400
colorYellow = #ffe500
colorWhite = #ffffff
colorPink = #ff00f0
colorBluelight = #31c0ff

colorWT1 = #90caf9
colorWT2 = #0d47a1

colorWT2_ = #131722

colormacdWT1a = #4caf58
colormacdWT1b = #af4c4c
colormacdWT1c = #7ee57e
colormacdWT1d = #ff3535

colormacdWT2a = #305630
colormacdWT2b = #310101
colormacdWT2c = #132213
colormacdWT2d = #770000

// } PARAMETERS

// FUNCTIONS {

// Divergences
f_top_fractal(src) => src[4] < src[2] and src[3] < src[2] and src[2] > src[1] and src[2] > 
src[0]
f_bot_fractal(src) => src[4] > src[2] and src[3] > src[2] and src[2] < src[1] and src[2] < 
src[0]
f_fractalize(src) => f_top_fractal(src) ? 1 : f_bot_fractal(src) ? -1 : 0

f_findDivs(src, topLimit, botLimit, useLimits) =>
    fractalTop = f_fractalize(src) > 0 and (useLimits ? src[2] >= topLimit : true) ? src[2] : 
    na
    fractalBot = f_fractalize(src) < 0 and (useLimits ? src[2] <= botLimit : true) ? src[2] : 
    na
    highPrev = valuewhen(fractalTop, src[2], 0)[2]
    highPrice = valuewhen(fractalTop, high[2], 0)[2]
    lowPrev = valuewhen(fractalBot, src[2], 0)[2]
    lowPrice = valuewhen(fractalBot, low[2], 0)[2]
    bearSignal = fractalTop and high[2] > highPrice and src[2] < highPrev
    bullSignal = fractalBot and low[2] < lowPrice and src[2] > lowPrev
    bearDivHidden = fractalTop and high[2] < highPrice and src[2] > highPrev
    bullDivHidden = fractalBot and low[2] > lowPrice and src[2] < lowPrev
    [fractalTop, fractalBot, lowPrev, bearSignal, bullSignal, bearDivHidden, bullDivHidden, 
    highPrev]

// RSI+MFI
 f_rsimfi(_period, _multiplier, _tf) => security(syminfo.tickerid, _tf, sma(((close – open) / 
(high – low)) * _multiplier, _period) – rsiMFIPosY)

// WaveTrend
f_wavetrend(src, chlen, avg, malen, tf) =>
    tfsrc = security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, src)
    esa = ema(tfsrc, chlen)
    de = ema(abs(tfsrc – esa), chlen)
    ci = (tfsrc – esa) / (0.015 * de)
    wt1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, ema(ci, avg))
    wt2 = security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, sma(wt1, malen))
    wtVwap = wt1 – wt2
    wtOversold = wt2 <= osLevel
    wtOverbought = wt2 >= obLevel
    wtCross = cross(wt1, wt2)
    wtCrossUp = wt2 – wt1 <= 0
    wtCrossDown = wt2 – wt1 >= 0
    wtCrosslast = cross(wt1[2], wt2[2])
    wtCrossUplast = wt2[2] – wt1[2] <= 0
    wtCrossDownlast = wt2[2] – wt1[2] >= 0
    [wt1, wt2, wtOversold, wtOverbought, wtCross, wtCrossUp, wtCrossDown, wtCrosslast, 
    wtCrossUplast, wtCrossDownlast, wtVwap]

// Schaff Trend Cycle
f_tc(src, length, fastLength, slowLength) =>
    ema1 = ema(src, fastLength)
    ema2 = ema(src, slowLength)
    macdVal = ema1 – ema2
    alpha = lowest(macdVal, length)
    beta = highest(macdVal, length) – alpha
    gamma = (macdVal – alpha) / beta * 100
    gamma := beta > 0 ? gamma : nz(gamma[1])
    delta = gamma
    delta := na(delta[1]) ? delta : delta[1] + tcfactor * (gamma – delta[1])
    epsilon = lowest(delta, length)
    zeta = highest(delta, length) – epsilon
    eta = (delta – epsilon) / zeta * 100
    eta := zeta > 0 ? eta : nz(eta[1])
    stcReturn = eta
    stcReturn := na(stcReturn[1]) ? stcReturn : stcReturn[1] + tcfactor * (eta – stcReturn[1])
    stcReturn

// Stochastic RSI
f_stochrsi(_src, _stochlen, _rsilen, _smoothk, _smoothd, _log, _avg) =>
    src = _log ? log(_src) : _src
    rsi = rsi(src, _rsilen)
    kk = sma(stoch(rsi, rsi, rsi, _stochlen), _smoothk)
    d1 = sma(kk, _smoothd)
    avg_1 = avg(kk, d1)
    k = _avg ? avg_1 : kk
    [k, d1]

// MACD
f_macd(src, fastlen, slowlen, sigsmooth, tf) =>
    fast_ma = security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, ema(src, fastlen))
    slow_ma = security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, ema(src, slowlen))
    macd = fast_ma – slow_ma,
    signal = security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, sma(macd, sigsmooth))
    hist = macd – signal
    [macd, signal, hist]

// MACD Colors on WT
f_macdWTColors(tf) =>
    hrsimfi = f_rsimfi(rsiMFIperiod, rsiMFIMultiplier, tf)
    [macd, signal, hist] = f_macd(close, 28, 42, 9, macdWTColorsTF)
    macdup = macd >= signal
    macddown = macd <= signal
    macdWT1Color = macdup ? hrsimfi > 0 ? colormacdWT1c : colormacdWT1a : macddown ? hrsimfi < 
    0 ? colormacdWT1d : colormacdWT1b : na
    macdWT2Color = macdup ? hrsimfi < 0 ? colormacdWT2c : colormacdWT2a : macddown ? hrsimfi < 
    0 ? colormacdWT2d : colormacdWT2b : na
    [macdWT1Color, macdWT2Color]

 // Get higher timeframe candle
f_getTFCandle(_tf) =>
    _open = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), _tf, open, barmerge.gaps_off,  
    barmerge.lookahead_on)
    _close = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), _tf, close, barmerge.gaps_off, 
    barmerge.lookahead_on)
    _high = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), _tf, high, barmerge.gaps_off, 
    barmerge.lookahead_on)
    _low = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), _tf, low, barmerge.gaps_off, 
    barmerge.lookahead_on)
    hl2 = (_high + _low) / 2.0
    newBar = change(_open)
    candleBodyDir = _close > _open
    [candleBodyDir, newBar]

// Sommi flag
f_findSommiFlag(tf, wt1, wt2, rsimfi, wtCross, wtCrossUp, wtCrossDown) =>
[hwt1, hwt2, hwtOversold, hwtOverbought, hwtCross, hwtCrossUp, hwtCrossDown, hwtCrosslast, 
hwtCrossUplast, hwtCrossDownlast, hwtVwap] = f_wavetrend(wtMASource, wtChannelLen, 
wtAverageLen, wtMALen, tf)

bearPattern = rsimfi < soomiRSIMFIBearLevel and
wt2 > soomiFlagWTBearLevel and
wtCross and
wtCrossDown and
hwtVwap < sommiVwapBearLevel

bullPattern = rsimfi > soomiRSIMFIBullLevel and
wt2 < soomiFlagWTBullLevel and
wtCross and
wtCrossUp and
hwtVwap > sommiVwapBullLevel

[bearPattern, bullPattern, hwtVwap]

f_findSommiDiamond(tf, tf2, wt1, wt2, wtCross, wtCrossUp, wtCrossDown) =>
    [candleBodyDir, newBar] = f_getTFCandle(tf)
    [candleBodyDir2, newBar2] = f_getTFCandle(tf2)
    bearPattern = wt2 >= soomiDiamondWTBearLevel and
    wtCross and
    wtCrossDown and
    not candleBodyDir and
    not candleBodyDir2
    bullPattern = wt2 <= soomiDiamondWTBullLevel and
    wtCross and
    wtCrossUp and
    candleBodyDir and
    candleBodyDir2
    [bearPattern, bullPattern]

// } FUNCTIONS

// CALCULATE INDICATORS {

// RSI
rsi = rsi(rsiSRC, rsiLen)
rsiColor = rsi <= rsiOversold ? colorGreen : rsi >= rsiOverbought ? colorRed : colorPurple

// RSI + MFI Area
rsiMFI = f_rsimfi(rsiMFIperiod, rsiMFIMultiplier, timeframe.period)
rsiMFIColor = rsiMFI > 0 ? #3ee145 : #ff3d2e

// Calculates WaveTrend
[wt1, wt2, wtOversold, wtOverbought, wtCross, wtCrossUp, wtCrossDown, wtCross_last, 
wtCrossUp_last, wtCrossDown_last, wtVwap] = f_wavetrend(wtMASource, wtChannelLen, 
wtAverageLen, wtMALen, timeframe.period)

// Stochastic RSI
[stochK, stochD] = f_stochrsi(stochSRC, stochLen, stochRsiLen, stochKSmooth, stochDSmooth, 
stochUseLog, stochAvg)

// Schaff Trend Cycle
tcVal = f_tc(tcSRC, tclength, tcfastLength, tcslowLength)

// Sommi flag
[sommiBearish, sommiBullish, hvwap] = f_findSommiFlag(sommiVwapTF, wt1, wt2, rsiMFI, wtCross, 
wtCrossUp, wtCrossDown)

//Sommi diamond
[sommiBearishDiamond, sommiBullishDiamond] = f_findSommiDiamond(sommiHTCRes, sommiHTCRes2, 
wt1, wt2, wtCross, wtCrossUp, wtCrossDown)

// macd colors
[macdWT1Color, macdWT2Color] = f_macdWTColors(macdWTColorsTF)

// WT Divergences
[wtFractalTop, wtFractalBot, wtLow_prev, wtBearDiv, wtBullDiv, wtBearDivHidden, 
wtBullDivHidden] = f_findDivs(wt2, wtDivOBLevel, wtDivOSLevel, true)

[wtFractalTop_add, wtFractalBot_add, wtLow_prev_add, wtBearDiv_add, wtBullDiv_add, 
wtBearDivHidden_add, wtBullDivHidden_add] = f_findDivs(wt2, wtDivOBLevel_add, 
wtDivOSLevel_add, true)
[wtFractalTop_nl, wtFractalBot_nl, wtLow_prev_nl, wtBearDiv_nl, wtBullDiv_nl, 
wtBearDivHidden_nl, wtBullDivHidden_nl] = f_findDivs(wt2, 0, 0, false)

wtBearDivHidden_ = showHiddenDiv_nl ? wtBearDivHidden_nl : wtBearDivHidden
wtBullDivHidden_ = showHiddenDiv_nl ? wtBullDivHidden_nl : wtBullDivHidden

wtBearDivColor = (wtShowDiv and wtBearDiv) or (wtShowHiddenDiv and wtBearDivHidden_) ? 
colorRed : na
wtBullDivColor = (wtShowDiv and wtBullDiv) or (wtShowHiddenDiv and wtBullDivHidden_) ? 
colorGreen : na

wtBearDivColor_add = (wtShowDiv and (wtDivOBLevel_addshow and wtBearDiv_add)) or 
(wtShowHiddenDiv and (wtDivOBLevel_addshow and wtBearDivHidden_add)) ? #9a0202 : na
wtBullDivColor_add = (wtShowDiv and (wtDivOBLevel_addshow and wtBullDiv_add)) or 
(wtShowHiddenDiv and (wtDivOBLevel_addshow and wtBullDivHidden_add)) ? #1b5e20 : na

// RSI Divergences
[rsiFractalTop, rsiFractalBot, rsiLow_prev, rsiBearDiv, rsiBullDiv, rsiBearDivHidden, 
rsiBullDivHidden] = f_findDivs(rsi, rsiDivOBLevel, rsiDivOSLevel, true)
[rsiFractalTop_nl, rsiFractalBot_nl, rsiLow_prev_nl, rsiBearDiv_nl, rsiBullDiv_nl, 
rsiBearDivHidden_nl, rsiBullDivHidden_nl] = f_findDivs(rsi, 0, 0, false)

rsiBearDivHidden_ = showHiddenDiv_nl ? rsiBearDivHidden_nl : rsiBearDivHidden
rsiBullDivHidden_ = showHiddenDiv_nl ? rsiBullDivHidden_nl : rsiBullDivHidden

rsiBearDivColor = (rsiShowDiv and rsiBearDiv) or (rsiShowHiddenDiv and rsiBearDivHidden_) ? 
colorRed : na
rsiBullDivColor = (rsiShowDiv and rsiBullDiv) or (rsiShowHiddenDiv and rsiBullDivHidden_) ? 
colorGreen : na

// Stoch Divergences
[stochFractalTop, stochFractalBot, stochLow_prev, stochBearDiv, stochBullDiv, 
stochBearDivHidden, stochBullDivHidden] = f_findDivs(stochK, 0, 0, false)

stochBearDivColor = (stochShowDiv and stochBearDiv) or (stochShowHiddenDiv and 
stochBearDivHidden) ? colorRed : na
stochBullDivColor = (stochShowDiv and stochBullDiv) or (stochShowHiddenDiv and 
stochBullDivHidden) ? colorGreen : na

// Small Circles WT Cross
signalColor = wt2 – wt1 > 0 ? color.red : color.lime

// Buy signal.
buySignal = wtCross and wtCrossUp and wtOversold

buySignalDiv = (wtShowDiv and wtBullDiv) or
(wtShowDiv and wtBullDiv_add) or
(stochShowDiv and stochBullDiv) or
(rsiShowDiv and rsiBullDiv)

buySignalDiv_color = wtBullDiv ? colorGreen :
wtBullDiv_add ? color.new(colorGreen, 60) :
rsiShowDiv ? colorGreen : na

// Sell signal
sellSignal = wtCross and wtCrossDown and wtOverbought

sellSignalDiv = (wtShowDiv and wtBearDiv) or
(wtShowDiv and wtBearDiv_add) or
(stochShowDiv and stochBearDiv) or
(rsiShowDiv and rsiBearDiv)

sellSignalDiv_color = wtBearDiv ? colorRed :
wtBearDiv_add ? color.new(colorRed, 60) :
rsiBearDiv ? colorRed : na

// Gold Buy
lastRsi = valuewhen(wtFractalBot, rsi[2], 0)[2]
wtGoldBuy = ((wtShowDiv and wtBullDiv) or (rsiShowDiv and rsiBullDiv)) and
wtLow_prev <= osLevel3 and
wt2 > osLevel3 and
wtLow_prev – wt2 <= -5 and
lastRsi < 30

// } CALCULATE INDICATORS

// DRAW {
bgcolor(darkMode ? color.new(#000000, 80) : na)
zLine = plot(0, color = color.new(colorWhite, 50))

// MFI BAR
rsiMfiBarTopLine = plot(rsiMFIShow ? -95 : na, title = "MFI Bar TOP Line", transp = 100)
rsiMfiBarBottomLine = plot(rsiMFIShow ? -99 : na, title = "MFI Bar BOTTOM Line", transp = 100)
fill(rsiMfiBarTopLine, rsiMfiBarBottomLine, title = "MFI Bar Colors", color = rsiMFIColor, 
transp = 75)

// WT Areas
plot(wtShow ? wt1 : na, style = plot.style_area, title = "WT Wave 1", color = macdWTColorsShow 
? macdWT1Color : colorWT1, transp = 0)
plot(wtShow ? wt2 : na, style = plot.style_area, title = "WT Wave 2", color = macdWTColorsShow 
? macdWT2Color : darkMode ? colorWT2_ : colorWT2 , transp = 20)

// VWAP
plot(vwapShow ? wtVwap : na, title = "VWAP", color = colorYellow, style = plot.style_area, 
linewidth = 2, transp = 45)

// MFI AREA
rsiMFIplot = plot(rsiMFIShow ? rsiMFI: na, title = "RSI+MFI Area", color = rsiMFIColor, transp 
= 20)
fill(rsiMFIplot, zLine, rsiMFIColor, transp = 40)

// WT Div

plot(series = wtFractalTop ? wt2[2] : na, title = "WT Bearish Divergence", color = 
wtBearDivColor, linewidth = 2, offset = -2)
plot(series = wtFractalBot ? wt2[2] : na, title = "WT Bullish Divergence", color = 
wtBullDivColor, linewidth = 2, offset = -2)

// WT 2nd Div
plot(series = wtFractalTop_add ? wt2[2] : na, title = "WT 2nd Bearish Divergence", color = 
wtBearDivColor_add, linewidth = 2, offset = -2)
plot(series = wtFractalBot_add ? wt2[2] : na, title = "WT 2nd Bullish Divergence", color = 
wtBullDivColor_add, linewidth = 2, offset = -2)

// RSI
plot(rsiShow ? rsi : na, title = ‘RSI’, color = rsiColor, linewidth = 2, transp = 25)

// RSI Div
plot(series = rsiFractalTop ? rsi[2] : na, title= "RSI Bearish Divergence", color = 
rsiBearDivColor, linewidth = 1, offset = -2)
plot(series = rsiFractalBot ? rsi[2] : na, title= "RSI Bullish Divergence", color = 
rsiBullDivColor, linewidth = 1, offset = -2)

// Stochastic RSI
stochKplot = plot(stochShow ? stochK : na, title = "Stoch K", color = color.new(#21baf3, 0), 
linewidth = 2)
stochDplot = plot(stochShow ? stochD : na, title = "Stoch D", color = color.new(#673ab7, 60), 
linewidth = 1)
stochFillColor = stochK >= stochD ? color.new(#21baf3, 75) : color.new(#673ab7, 60)
fill(stochKplot, stochDplot, title=’KD Fill’, color=stochFillColor)

// Stoch Div
plot(series = stochFractalTop ? stochK[2] : na, title= "Stoch Bearish Divergence", color = 
stochBearDivColor, linewidth = 1, offset = -2)
plot(series = stochFractalBot ? stochK[2] : na, title= "Stoch Bullish Divergence", color = 
stochBullDivColor, linewidth = 1, offset = -2)

// Schaff Trend Cycle
plot(tcLine ? tcVal : na, color = color.new(#673ab7, 25), linewidth = 2, title = "Schaff Trend 
Cycle 1")
plot(tcLine ? tcVal : na, color = color.new(colorWhite, 50), linewidth = 1, title = "Schaff 
Trend Cycle 2")

// Draw Overbought & Oversold lines
plot(obLevel, title = "Over Bought Level 1", color = colorWhite, linewidth = 1, style = 
plot.style_circles, transp = 85)
plot(obLevel2, title = "Over Bought Level 2", color = colorWhite, linewidth = 1, style = 
plot.style_stepline, transp = 85)
plot(obLevel3, title = "Over Bought Level 3", color = colorWhite, linewidth = 1, style = 
plot.style_circles, transp = 95)

plot(osLevel, title = "Over Sold Level 1", color = colorWhite, linewidth = 1, style = 
plot.style_circles, transp = 85)
plot(osLevel2, title = "Over Sold Level 2", color = colorWhite, linewidth = 1, style = 
plot.style_stepline, transp = 85)

// Sommi flag
plotchar(sommiFlagShow and sommiBearish ? 108 : na, title = "Sommi bearish flag", char=’⚑’, 
color = colorPink, location = location.absolute, size = size.tiny, transp = 0)
plotchar(sommiFlagShow and sommiBullish ? -108 : na, title = "Sommi bullish flag", char=’⚑’, 
color = colorBluelight, location = location.absolute, size = size.tiny, transp = 0)
plot(sommiShowVwap ? ema(hvwap, 3) : na, title = "Sommi higher VWAP", color = colorYellow, 
linewidth = 2, style = plot.style_line, transp = 15)

// Sommi diamond
plotchar(sommiDiamondShow and sommiBearishDiamond ? 108 : na, title = "Sommi bearish diamond", 
char=’◆’, color = colorPink, location = location.absolute, size = size.tiny, transp = 0)
plotchar(sommiDiamondShow and sommiBullishDiamond ? -108 : na, title = "Sommi bullish 
diamond", char=’◆’, color = colorBluelight, location = location.absolute, size = size.tiny, 
transp = 0)

// Circles
plot(wtCross ? wt2 : na, title = "Buy and sell circle", color = signalColor, style = 
plot.style_circles, linewidth = 3, transp = 15)

plotchar(wtBuyShow and buySignal ? -107 : na, title = "Buy circle", char=’·’, color = 
colorGreen, location = location.absolute, size = size.small, transp = 50)
plotchar(wtSellShow and sellSignal ? 105 : na , title = "Sell circle", char=’·’, color = 
colorRed, location = location.absolute, size = size.small, transp = 50)

plotchar(wtDivShow and buySignalDiv ? -106 : na, title = "Divergence buy circle", char=’•’, 
color = buySignalDiv_color, location = location.absolute, size = size.small, offset = -2, 
transp = 15)
plotchar(wtDivShow and sellSignalDiv ? 106 : na, title = "Divergence sell circle", char=’•’, 
color = sellSignalDiv_color, location = location.absolute, size = size.small, offset = -2, 
transp = 15)

plotchar(wtGoldBuy and wtGoldShow ? -106 : na, title = "Gold buy gold circle", char=’•’, color 
= colorOrange, location = location.absolute, size = size.small, offset = -2, transp = 15)

// } DRAW

// ALERTS {

// BUY
alertcondition(buySignal, ‘Buy (Big green circle)’, ‘Green circle WaveTrend Oversold’)
alertcondition(buySignalDiv, ‘Buy (Big green circle + Div)’, ‘Buy & WT Bullish Divergence & WT 
Overbought’)
alertcondition(wtGoldBuy, ‘GOLD Buy (Big GOLDEN circle)’, ‘Green & GOLD circle WaveTrend 
Overbought’)
alertcondition(sommiBullish or sommiBullishDiamond, ‘Sommi bullish flag/diamond’, ‘Blue 
flag/diamond’)
alertcondition(wtCross and wtCrossUp, ‘Buy (Small green dot)’, ‘Buy small circle’)

// SELL
alertcondition(sommiBearish or sommiBearishDiamond, ‘Sommi bearish flag/diamond’, ‘Purple 
flag/diamond’)
alertcondition(sellSignal, ‘Sell (Big red circle)’, ‘Red Circle WaveTrend Overbought’)
alertcondition(sellSignalDiv, ‘Sell (Big red circle + Div)’, ‘Buy & WT Bearish Divergence & WT 
Overbought’)
alertcondition(wtCross and wtCrossDown, ‘Sell (Small red dot)’, ‘Sell small circle’)

// } ALERTS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another bad copy-paste job.
There were multiple issues with this script (mostly indentation), and the minus signs were hyphens.

This will compile and plot.

```
//@version=4
study(title = "VuManChu B Divergences", shorttitle = "VMC Cipher_B_Divergences")

// PARAMETERS {

// WaveTrend
wtShow = input(true, title = "Show WaveTrend", type = input.bool)
wtBuyShow = input(true, title = "Show Buy dots", type = input.bool)
wtGoldShow = input(true, title = "Show Gold dots", type = input.bool)
wtSellShow = input(true, title = "Show Sell dots", type = input.bool)
wtDivShow = input(true, title = "Show Div. dots", type = input.bool)
vwapShow = input(true, title = "Show Fast WT", type = input.bool)
wtChannelLen = input(9, title = "WT Channel Length", type = input.integer)
wtAverageLen = input(12, title = "WT Average Length", type = input.integer)
wtMASource = input(hlc3, title = "WT MA Source", type = input.source)
wtMALen = input(3, title = "WT MA Length", type = input.integer)

// WaveTrend Overbought & Oversold lines
obLevel = input(53, title = "WT Overbought Level 1", type = input.integer)
obLevel2 = input(60, title = "WT Overbought Level 2", type = input.integer)
obLevel3 = input(100, title = "WT Overbought Level 3", type = input.integer)
osLevel = input(-53, title = "WT Oversold Level 1", type = input.integer)
osLevel2 = input(-60, title = "WT Oversold Level 2", type = input.integer)
osLevel3 = input(-75, title = "WT Oversold Level 3", type = input.integer)

// Divergence WT
wtShowDiv = input(true, title = "Show WT Regular Divergences", type = input.bool)
wtShowHiddenDiv = input(false, title = "Show WT Hidden Divergences", type = input.bool)
showHiddenDiv_nl = input(true, title = "Not apply OB/OS Limits on Hidden Divergences", type = input.bool)
wtDivOBLevel = input(45, title = "WT Bearish Divergence min", type = input.integer)
wtDivOSLevel = input(-65, title = "WT Bullish Divergence min", type = input.integer)

// Divergence extra range
wtDivOBLevel_addshow = input(true, title = "Show 2nd WT Regular Divergences", type = input.bool)
wtDivOBLevel_add = input(15, title = "WT 2nd Bearish Divergence", type = input.integer)
wtDivOSLevel_add = input(-40, title = "WT 2nd Bullish Divergence 15 min", type = input.integer)

// RSI+MFI
rsiMFIShow = input(true, title = "Show MFI", type = input.bool)
rsiMFIperiod = input(60,title = "MFI Period", type = input.integer)
rsiMFIMultiplier = input(150, title = "MFI Area multiplier", type = input.float)
rsiMFIPosY = input(2.5, title = "MFI Area Y Pos", type = input.float)

// RSI
rsiShow = input(false, title = "Show RSI", type = input.bool)
rsiSRC = input(close, title = "RSI Source", type = input.source)
rsiLen = input(14, title = "RSI Length", type = input.integer)
rsiOversold = input(30, title = "RSI Oversold", minval = 50, maxval = 100, type = input.integer)
rsiOverbought = input(60, title = "RSI Overbought", minval = 0, maxval = 50, type = input.integer)

// Divergence RSI
rsiShowDiv = input(false, title = "Show RSI Regular Divergences", type = input.bool)
rsiShowHiddenDiv = input(false, title = "Show RSI Hidden Divergences", type = input.bool)
rsiDivOBLevel = input(60, title = "RSI Bearish Divergence min", type = input.integer)
rsiDivOSLevel = input(30, title = "RSI Bullish Divergence min", type = input.integer)

// RSI Stochastic
stochShow = input(true, title = "Show Stochastic RSI", type = input.bool)
stochUseLog = input(true, title= "Use Log?", type = input.bool)
stochAvg = input(false, title= "Use Average of both K & D", type = input.bool)
stochSRC = input(close, title = "Stochastic RSI Source", type = input.source)
stochLen = input(14, title = "Stochastic RSI Length", type = input.integer)
stochRsiLen = input(14, title = "RSI Length", type = input.integer)
stochKSmooth = input(3, title = "Stochastic RSI K Smooth", type = input.integer)
stochDSmooth = input(3, title = "Stochastic RSI D Smooth", type = input.integer)

// Divergence stoch
stochShowDiv = input(false, title = "Show Stoch Regular Divergences", type = input.bool)
stochShowHiddenDiv = input(false, title = "Show Stoch Hidden Divergences", type = input.bool)

// Schaff Trend Cycle
tcLine = input(false, title = "Show Schaff TC line", type=input.bool)
tcSRC = input(close, title = "Schaff TC Source", type = input.source)
tclength = input(10, title= "Schaff TC", type=input.integer)
tcfastLength = input(23, title= "Schaff TC Fast Lenght", type=input.integer)
tcslowLength = input(50, title= "Schaff TC Slow Length", type=input.integer)
tcfactor = input(0.5, title= "Schaff TC Factor", type=input.float)

// Sommi Flag
sommiFlagShow = input(false, title = "Show Sommi flag", type = input.bool)
sommiShowVwap = input(false, title = "Show Sommi F. Wave", type = input.bool)
sommiVwapTF = input("720", title = "Sommi F. Wave timeframe", type = input.string)
sommiVwapBearLevel = input(0, title = "F. Wave Bear Level (less than)", type = input.integer)
sommiVwapBullLevel = input(0, title = "F. Wave Bull Level (more than)", type = input.integer)
soomiFlagWTBearLevel = input(0, title = "WT Bear Level (more than)", type = input.integer)
soomiFlagWTBullLevel = input(0, title = "WT Bull Level (less than)", type = input.integer)
soomiRSIMFIBearLevel = input(0, title = "Money flow Bear Level (less than)", type = input.integer)
soomiRSIMFIBullLevel = input(0, title = "Money flow Bull Level (more than)", type = input.integer)

// Sommi Diamond
sommiDiamondShow = input(false, title = "Show Sommi diamond", type = input.bool)
sommiHTCRes = input("60", title = "HTF Candle Res. 1", type = input.string)
sommiHTCRes2 = input("240", title = "HTF Candle Res. 2", type = input.string)
soomiDiamondWTBearLevel = input(0, title = "WT Bear Level (More than)", type = input.integer)
soomiDiamondWTBullLevel = input(0, title = "WT Bull Level (Less than)", type = input.integer)

// macd Colors
macdWTColorsShow = input(false, title = "Show MACD Colors", type = input.bool)
macdWTColorsTF = input("240", title = "MACD Colors MACD TF", type = input.string)

darkMode = input(false, title = "Dark mode", type = input.bool)

// Colors
colorRed = #ff0000
colorPurple = #e600e6
colorGreen = #3fff00
colorOrange = #e2a400
colorYellow = #ffe500
colorWhite = #ffffff
colorPink = #ff00f0
colorBluelight = #31c0ff

colorWT1 = #90caf9
colorWT2 = #0d47a1

colorWT2_ = #131722

colormacdWT1a = #4caf58
colormacdWT1b = #af4c4c
colormacdWT1c = #7ee57e
colormacdWT1d = #ff3535

colormacdWT2a = #305630
colormacdWT2b = #310101
colormacdWT2c = #132213
colormacdWT2d = #770000

// } PARAMETERS

// FUNCTIONS {

// Divergences
f_top_fractal(src) => src[4] < src[2] and src[3] < src[2] and src[2] > src[1] and src[2] > src[0]
f_bot_fractal(src) => src[4] > src[2] and src[3] > src[2] and src[2] < src[1] and src[2] < src[0]
f_fractalize(src) => f_top_fractal(src) ? 1 : f_bot_fractal(src) ? -1 : 0

f_findDivs(src, topLimit, botLimit, useLimits) =>
    fractalTop = f_fractalize(src) > 0 and (useLimits ? src[2] >= topLimit : true) ? src[2] : na
    fractalBot = f_fractalize(src) < 0 and (useLimits ? src[2] <= botLimit : true) ? src[2] : na
    highPrev = valuewhen(fractalTop, src[2], 0)[2]
    highPrice = valuewhen(fractalTop, high[2], 0)[2]
    lowPrev = valuewhen(fractalBot, src[2], 0)[2]
    lowPrice = valuewhen(fractalBot, low[2], 0)[2]
    bearSignal = fractalTop and high[2] > highPrice and src[2] < highPrev
    bullSignal = fractalBot and low[2] < lowPrice and src[2] > lowPrev
    bearDivHidden = fractalTop and high[2] < highPrice and src[2] > highPrev
    bullDivHidden = fractalBot and low[2] > lowPrice and src[2] < lowPrev
    [fractalTop, fractalBot, lowPrev, bearSignal, bullSignal, bearDivHidden, bullDivHidden] //, highPrev]

// RSI+MFI
f_rsimfi(_period, _multiplier, _tf) => 
    security(syminfo.tickerid, _tf, sma(((close - open) / (high - low)) * _multiplier, _period)) - rsiMFIPosY

// WaveTrend
f_wavetrend(src, chlen, avg, malen, tf) =>
    tfsrc = security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, src)
    esa = ema(tfsrc, chlen)
    de = ema(abs(tfsrc - esa), chlen)
    ci = (tfsrc - esa) / (0.015 * de)
    wt1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, ema(ci, avg))
    wt2 = security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, sma(wt1, malen))
    wtVwap = wt1 - wt2
    wtOversold = wt2 <= osLevel
    wtOverbought = wt2 >= obLevel
    wtCross = cross(wt1, wt2)
    wtCrossUp = wt2 - wt1 <= 0
    wtCrossDown = wt2 - wt1 >= 0
    wtCrosslast = cross(wt1[2], wt2[2])
    wtCrossUplast = wt2[2] - wt1[2] <= 0
    wtCrossDownlast = wt2[2] - wt1[2] >= 0
    [wt1, wt2, wtOversold, wtOverbought, wtCross, wtCrossUp, wtCrossDown, wtCrosslast, wtCrossUplast, wtCrossDownlast, wtVwap]

// Schaff Trend Cycle
f_tc(src, length, fastLength, slowLength) =>
    ema1 = ema(src, fastLength)
    ema2 = ema(src, slowLength)
    macdVal = ema1 - ema2
    alpha = lowest(macdVal, length)
    beta = highest(macdVal, length) - alpha
    gamma = (macdVal - alpha) / beta * 100
    gamma := beta > 0 ? gamma : nz(gamma[1])
    delta = gamma
    delta := na(delta[1]) ? delta : delta[1] + tcfactor * (gamma - delta[1])
    epsilon = lowest(delta, length)
    zeta = highest(delta, length) - epsilon
    eta = (delta - epsilon) / zeta * 100
    eta := zeta > 0 ? eta : nz(eta[1])
    stcReturn = eta
    stcReturn := na(stcReturn[1]) ? stcReturn : stcReturn[1] + tcfactor * (eta - stcReturn[1])
    stcReturn

// Stochastic RSI
f_stochrsi(_src, _stochlen, _rsilen, _smoothk, _smoothd, _log, _avg) =>
    src = _log ? log(_src) : _src
    rsi = rsi(src, _rsilen)
    kk = sma(stoch(rsi, rsi, rsi, _stochlen), _smoothk)
    d1 = sma(kk, _smoothd)
    avg_1 = avg(kk, d1)
    k = _avg ? avg_1 : kk
    [k, d1]

// MACD
f_macd(src, fastlen, slowlen, sigsmooth, tf) =>
    fast_ma = security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, ema(src, fastlen))
    slow_ma = security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, ema(src, slowlen))
    macd = fast_ma - slow_ma,
    signal = security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, sma(macd, sigsmooth))
    hist = macd - signal
    [macd, signal, hist]

// MACD Colors on WT
f_macdWTColors(tf) =>
    hrsimfi = f_rsimfi(rsiMFIperiod, rsiMFIMultiplier, tf)
    [macd, signal, hist] = f_macd(close, 28, 42, 9, macdWTColorsTF)
    macdup = macd >= signal
    macddown = macd <= signal
    macdWT1Color = macdup ? hrsimfi > 0 ? colormacdWT1c : colormacdWT1a : macddown ? hrsimfi < 0 ? colormacdWT1d : colormacdWT1b : na
    macdWT2Color = macdup ? hrsimfi < 0 ? colormacdWT2c : colormacdWT2a : macddown ? hrsimfi < 0 ? colormacdWT2d : colormacdWT2b : na
    [macdWT1Color, macdWT2Color]

 // Get higher timeframe candle
f_getTFCandle(_tf) =>
    _open = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), _tf, open, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
    _close = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), _tf, close, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
    _high = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), _tf, high, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
    _low = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), _tf, low, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
    // hl2 = (_high + _low) / 2.0
    newBar = change(_open)
    candleBodyDir = _close > _open
    [candleBodyDir, newBar]

// Sommi flag
f_findSommiFlag(tf, wt1, wt2, rsimfi, wtCross, wtCrossUp, wtCrossDown) =>
    [hwt1, hwt2, hwtOversold, hwtOverbought, hwtCross, hwtCrossUp, hwtCrossDown, hwtCrosslast, hwtCrossUplast, hwtCrossDownlast, hwtVwap] = f_wavetrend(wtMASource, wtChannelLen, wtAverageLen, wtMALen, tf)
    bearPattern = rsimfi < soomiRSIMFIBearLevel and wt2 > soomiFlagWTBearLevel and wtCross and wtCrossDown and hwtVwap < sommiVwapBearLevel
    bullPattern = rsimfi > soomiRSIMFIBullLevel and wt2 < soomiFlagWTBullLevel and wtCross and wtCrossUp and hwtVwap > sommiVwapBullLevel
    [bearPattern, bullPattern, hwtVwap]

f_findSommiDiamond(tf, tf2, wt1, wt2, wtCross, wtCrossUp, wtCrossDown) =>
    [candleBodyDir, newBar] = f_getTFCandle(tf)
    [candleBodyDir2, newBar2] = f_getTFCandle(tf2)
    bearPattern = wt2 >= soomiDiamondWTBearLevel and wtCross and wtCrossDown and not candleBodyDir and not candleBodyDir2
    bullPattern = wt2 <= soomiDiamondWTBullLevel and wtCross and wtCrossUp and candleBodyDir and candleBodyDir2
    [bearPattern, bullPattern]

// } FUNCTIONS

// CALCULATE INDICATORS {

// RSI
rsi = rsi(rsiSRC, rsiLen)
rsiColor = rsi <= rsiOversold ? colorGreen : rsi >= rsiOverbought ? colorRed : colorPurple

// RSI + MFI Area
rsiMFI = f_rsimfi(rsiMFIperiod, rsiMFIMultiplier, timeframe.period)
rsiMFIColor = rsiMFI > 0 ? #3ee145 : #ff3d2e

// Calculates WaveTrend
[wt1, wt2, wtOversold, wtOverbought, wtCross, wtCrossUp, wtCrossDown, wtCross_last, wtCrossUp_last, wtCrossDown_last, wtVwap] = f_wavetrend(wtMASource, wtChannelLen, wtAverageLen, wtMALen, timeframe.period)

// Stochastic RSI
[stochK, stochD] = f_stochrsi(stochSRC, stochLen, stochRsiLen, stochKSmooth, stochDSmooth, stochUseLog, stochAvg)

// Schaff Trend Cycle
tcVal = f_tc(tcSRC, tclength, tcfastLength, tcslowLength)

// Sommi flag
[sommiBearish, sommiBullish, hvwap] = f_findSommiFlag(sommiVwapTF, wt1, wt2, rsiMFI, wtCross, wtCrossUp, wtCrossDown)

//Sommi diamond
[sommiBearishDiamond, sommiBullishDiamond] = f_findSommiDiamond(sommiHTCRes, sommiHTCRes2, wt1, wt2, wtCross, wtCrossUp, wtCrossDown)

// macd colors
[macdWT1Color, macdWT2Color] = f_macdWTColors(macdWTColorsTF)

// WT Divergences
[wtFractalTop, wtFractalBot, wtLow_prev, wtBearDiv, wtBullDiv, wtBearDivHidden, wtBullDivHidden] = f_findDivs(wt2, wtDivOBLevel, wtDivOSLevel, true)

[wtFractalTop_add, wtFractalBot_add, wtLow_prev_add, wtBearDiv_add, wtBullDiv_add, wtBearDivHidden_add, wtBullDivHidden_add] = f_findDivs(wt2, wtDivOBLevel_add, wtDivOSLevel_add, true)
[wtFractalTop_nl, wtFractalBot_nl, wtLow_prev_nl, wtBearDiv_nl, wtBullDiv_nl, wtBearDivHidden_nl, wtBullDivHidden_nl] = f_findDivs(wt2, 0, 0, false)

wtBearDivHidden_ = showHiddenDiv_nl ? wtBearDivHidden_nl : wtBearDivHidden
wtBullDivHidden_ = showHiddenDiv_nl ? wtBullDivHidden_nl : wtBullDivHidden

wtBearDivColor = (wtShowDiv and wtBearDiv) or (wtShowHiddenDiv and wtBearDivHidden_) ? colorRed : na
wtBullDivColor = (wtShowDiv and wtBullDiv) or (wtShowHiddenDiv and wtBullDivHidden_) ? colorGreen : na

wtBearDivColor_add = (wtShowDiv and (wtDivOBLevel_addshow and wtBearDiv_add)) or (wtShowHiddenDiv and (wtDivOBLevel_addshow and wtBearDivHidden_add)) ? #9a0202 : na
wtBullDivColor_add = (wtShowDiv and (wtDivOBLevel_addshow and wtBullDiv_add)) or (wtShowHiddenDiv and (wtDivOBLevel_addshow and wtBullDivHidden_add)) ? #1b5e20 : na

// RSI Divergences
[rsiFractalTop, rsiFractalBot, rsiLow_prev, rsiBearDiv, rsiBullDiv, rsiBearDivHidden, rsiBullDivHidden] = f_findDivs(rsi, rsiDivOBLevel, rsiDivOSLevel, true) 
[rsiFractalTop_nl, rsiFractalBot_nl, rsiLow_prev_nl, rsiBearDiv_nl, rsiBullDiv_nl, rsiBearDivHidden_nl, rsiBullDivHidden_nl] = f_findDivs(rsi, 0, 0, false)

rsiBearDivHidden_ = showHiddenDiv_nl ? rsiBearDivHidden_nl : rsiBearDivHidden
rsiBullDivHidden_ = showHiddenDiv_nl ? rsiBullDivHidden_nl : rsiBullDivHidden

rsiBearDivColor = (rsiShowDiv and rsiBearDiv) or (rsiShowHiddenDiv and rsiBearDivHidden_) ? colorRed : na
rsiBullDivColor = (rsiShowDiv and rsiBullDiv) or (rsiShowHiddenDiv and rsiBullDivHidden_) ? colorGreen : na

// Stoch Divergences
[stochFractalTop, stochFractalBot, stochLow_prev, stochBearDiv, stochBullDiv, stochBearDivHidden, stochBullDivHidden] = f_findDivs(stochK, 0, 0, false)

stochBearDivColor = (stochShowDiv and stochBearDiv) or (stochShowHiddenDiv and stochBearDivHidden) ? colorRed : na
stochBullDivColor = (stochShowDiv and stochBullDiv) or (stochShowHiddenDiv and stochBullDivHidden) ? colorGreen : na

// Small Circles WT Cross
signalColor = wt2 - wt1 > 0 ? color.red : color.lime

// Buy signal.
buySignal = wtCross and wtCrossUp and wtOversold

buySignalDiv = (wtShowDiv and wtBullDiv) or (wtShowDiv and wtBullDiv_add) or (stochShowDiv and stochBullDiv) or (rsiShowDiv and rsiBullDiv)

buySignalDiv_color = wtBullDiv ? colorGreen : wtBullDiv_add ? color.new(colorGreen, 60) : rsiShowDiv ? colorGreen : na

// Sell signal
sellSignal = wtCross and wtCrossDown and wtOverbought

sellSignalDiv = (wtShowDiv and wtBearDiv) or (wtShowDiv and wtBearDiv_add) or (stochShowDiv and stochBearDiv) or (rsiShowDiv and rsiBearDiv)

sellSignalDiv_color = wtBearDiv ? colorRed : wtBearDiv_add ? color.new(colorRed, 60) : rsiBearDiv ? colorRed : na

// Gold Buy
lastRsi = valuewhen(wtFractalBot, rsi[2], 0)[2]
wtGoldBuy = ((wtShowDiv and wtBullDiv) or (rsiShowDiv and rsiBullDiv)) and wtLow_prev <= osLevel3 and wt2 > osLevel3 and wtLow_prev - wt2 <= -5 and lastRsi < 30

// } CALCULATE INDICATORS

// DRAW {
bgcolor(darkMode ? color.new(#000000, 80) : na)
zLine = plot(0, color = color.new(colorWhite, 50))

// MFI BAR
rsiMfiBarTopLine = plot(rsiMFIShow ? -95 : na, title = "MFI Bar TOP Line", transp = 100)
rsiMfiBarBottomLine = plot(rsiMFIShow ? -99 : na, title = "MFI Bar BOTTOM Line", transp = 100)
fill(rsiMfiBarTopLine, rsiMfiBarBottomLine, title = "MFI Bar Colors", color = rsiMFIColor, transp = 75)

// WT Areas
plot(wtShow ? wt1 : na, style = plot.style_area, title = "WT Wave 1", color = macdWTColorsShow ? macdWT1Color : colorWT1, transp = 0)
plot(wtShow ? wt2 : na, style = plot.style_area, title = "WT Wave 2", color = macdWTColorsShow ? macdWT2Color : darkMode ? colorWT2_ : colorWT2 , transp = 20)

// VWAP
plot(vwapShow ? wtVwap : na, title = "VWAP", color = colorYellow, style = plot.style_area, linewidth = 2, transp = 45)

// MFI AREA
rsiMFIplot = plot(rsiMFIShow ? rsiMFI: na, title = "RSI+MFI Area", color = rsiMFIColor, transp = 20)
fill(rsiMFIplot, zLine, rsiMFIColor, transp = 40)

// WT Div

plot(series = wtFractalTop ? wt2[2] : na, title = "WT Bearish Divergence", color = wtBearDivColor, linewidth = 2, offset = -2)
plot(series = wtFractalBot ? wt2[2] : na, title = "WT Bullish Divergence", color = wtBullDivColor, linewidth = 2, offset = -2)

// WT 2nd Div
plot(series = wtFractalTop_add ? wt2[2] : na, title = "WT 2nd Bearish Divergence", color = wtBearDivColor_add, linewidth = 2, offset = -2)
plot(series = wtFractalBot_add ? wt2[2] : na, title = "WT 2nd Bullish Divergence", color = wtBullDivColor_add, linewidth = 2, offset = -2)

// RSI
plot(rsiShow ? rsi : na, title = "RSI", color = rsiColor, linewidth = 2, transp = 25)

// RSI Div
plot(series = rsiFractalTop ? rsi[2] : na, title= "RSI Bearish Divergence", color = rsiBearDivColor, linewidth = 1, offset = -2)
plot(series = rsiFractalBot ? rsi[2] : na, title= "RSI Bullish Divergence", color = rsiBullDivColor, linewidth = 1, offset = -2)

// Stochastic RSI
stochKplot = plot(stochShow ? stochK : na, title = "Stoch K", color = color.new(#21baf3, 0),  linewidth = 2)
stochDplot = plot(stochShow ? stochD : na, title = "Stoch D", color = color.new(#673ab7, 60), linewidth = 1)
stochFillColor = stochK >= stochD ? color.new(#21baf3, 75) : color.new(#673ab7, 60)
fill(stochKplot, stochDplot, title="KD Fill", color=stochFillColor)

// Stoch Div
plot(series = stochFractalTop ? stochK[2] : na, title= "Stoch Bearish Divergence", color = stochBearDivColor, linewidth = 1, offset = -2)
plot(series = stochFractalBot ? stochK[2] : na, title= "Stoch Bullish Divergence", color = stochBullDivColor, linewidth = 1, offset = -2)

// Schaff Trend Cycle
plot(tcLine ? tcVal : na, color = color.new(#673ab7, 25), linewidth = 2, title = "Schaff Trend Cycle 1")
plot(tcLine ? tcVal : na, color = color.new(colorWhite, 50), linewidth = 1, title = "Schaff Trend Cycle 2")

// Draw Overbought & Oversold lines
plot(obLevel, title = "Over Bought Level 1", color = colorWhite, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_circles, transp = 85)
plot(obLevel2, title = "Over Bought Level 2", color = colorWhite, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_stepline, transp = 85)
plot(obLevel3, title = "Over Bought Level 3", color = colorWhite, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_circles, transp = 95)

plot(osLevel, title = "Over Sold Level 1", color = colorWhite, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_circles, transp = 85)
plot(osLevel2, title = "Over Sold Level 2", color = colorWhite, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_stepline, transp = 85)

// Sommi flag
plotchar(sommiFlagShow and sommiBearish ? 108 : na, title = "Sommi bearish flag", char="⚑", color = colorPink, location = location.absolute, size = size.tiny, transp = 0)
plotchar(sommiFlagShow and sommiBullish ? -108 : na, title = "Sommi bullish flag", char="⚑", color = colorBluelight, location = location.absolute, size = size.tiny, transp = 0)
plot(sommiShowVwap ? ema(hvwap, 3) : na, title = "Sommi higher VWAP", color = colorYellow, linewidth = 2, style = plot.style_line, transp = 15)

// Sommi diamond
plotchar(sommiDiamondShow and sommiBearishDiamond ? 108 : na, title = "Sommi bearish diamond", char="◆", color = colorPink, location = location.absolute, size = size.tiny, transp = 0)
plotchar(sommiDiamondShow and sommiBullishDiamond ? -108 : na, title = "Sommi bullish diamond", char="◆", color = colorBluelight, location = location.absolute, size = size.tiny, transp = 0)

// Circles
plot(wtCross ? wt2 : na, title = "Buy and sell circle", color = signalColor, style = plot.style_circles, linewidth = 3, transp = 15)

plotchar(wtBuyShow and buySignal ? -107 : na, title = "Buy circle", char="·", color = colorGreen, location = location.absolute, size = size.small, transp = 50)
plotchar(wtSellShow and sellSignal ? 105 : na , title = "Sell circle", char="·", color = colorRed, location = location.absolute, size = size.small, transp = 50)

plotchar(wtDivShow and buySignalDiv ? -106 : na, title = "Divergence buy circle", char="•", color = buySignalDiv_color, location = location.absolute, size = size.small, offset = -2, transp = 15)
plotchar(wtDivShow and sellSignalDiv ? 106 : na, title = "Divergence sell circle", char="•", color = sellSignalDiv_color, location = location.absolute, size = size.small, offset = -2, transp = 15)

plotchar(wtGoldBuy and wtGoldShow ? -106 : na, title = "Gold buy gold circle", char="•", color = colorOrange, location = location.absolute, size = size.small, offset = -2, transp = 15)

// } DRAW

// ALERTS {

// BUY
alertcondition(buySignal, "Buy (Big green circle)", "Green circle WaveTrend Oversold")
alertcondition(buySignalDiv, "Buy (Big green circle + Div)", "Buy & WT Bullish Divergence & WT Overbought")
alertcondition(wtGoldBuy, "GOLD Buy (Big GOLDEN circle)", "Green & GOLD circle WaveTrend Overbought")
alertcondition(sommiBullish or sommiBullishDiamond, "Sommi bullish flag/diamond", "Blue flag/diamond")
alertcondition(wtCross and wtCrossUp, "Buy (Small green dot)", "Buy small circle")

// SELL
alertcondition(sommiBearish or sommiBearishDiamond, "Sommi bearish flag/diamond", "Purple flag/diamond")
alertcondition(sellSignal, "Sell (Big red circle)", "Red Circle WaveTrend Overbought")
alertcondition(sellSignalDiv, "Sell (Big red circle + Div)", "Buy & WT Bearish Divergence & WT Overbought")
alertcondition(wtCross and wtCrossDown, "Sell (Small red dot)", "Sell small circle")

// } ALERTS
```

But why go through all that trouble?
The original code can be found here: [VuManChu Cipher B + Divergences](https://www.tradingview.com/script/Msm4SjwI-VuManChu-Cipher-B-Divergences/).